# How to replace each letter of the message I want to hide by the letter that is n rows further in the alphabetical order In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how to replace each letter of the message I want to hide
by the letter that is n rows further in the alphabetical order.

The thing I really don't get is the "alphabetical order" I immediately thought of using sort but how well would sort work?

So I thought maybe I should use the closest letter to the letter I want to replace? After all it's in alphabetical order.

I can do it manually but I want it to be automatic depending on what I want to hide

for ex : I specify right here to replace msg[0] by msg[5] and msg[5] by msg[0] is it ok or should I use a more "automatic" way to do it i.e. with i and a loop?

```
key = 4
msg = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'I', 'O', 'N']


def cipher_cesar(msg,key):

    msg[0],msg[5] = msg[5], msg[0]
                 
                 
    print(msg)
    answer = int(input("insert the key to find word"))
    if answer == key:
         
        return decipher_cesar(msg,answer)
       



def decipher_cesar(msg,key):
    
    
    msg[5],msg[0] = msg[0], msg[5]
    print(msg)
    
    
print(cipher_cesar(msg,key))
```

And by replace it means swap the two letters. If we find the key that allows to decipher the word it must be back to normal

EDIT 1 : In the hidden message all the letters should be replaced by their closest letter (by alphabetical order) so what i've tried above is wrong

EDIT 2 : I tried with ord() but it doesn't works anyway plus I want more a global thing rather than specifiying m[0] or the first letter I want to swap each letter with their closest letter in the list

```
m = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'I', 'O' , 'N']
mzero = m[0]


for i in range(len(m)-1):
    listes = []
    result = ord(mzero) - ord(m[i+1])
    print(f'result of {ord(mzero)} - {ord(m[i+1])}:', result)
    listes.append(abs(result))
    
    print(listes)
    
    if ord(mzero) - ord(m[i]) == min(listes):
        mzero, m[i] = m[i], mzero
        print(m)
        print('The closest value is :', min(listes))
```

I find a turorial on it but it's with numpy and I want to do it without any library https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/find+index+of+nearest+value+python

Comment: [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) seems appropriate here, along with the inverse, `chr()`

Comment: How with ord() ?

Comment: I don't get how I should use ord() in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Caesar cipher text, you could use something like:

```py
import string

def caesar_cipher(msg: str, shift: int) -> str:
    assert all(l in string.ascii_lowercase for l in msg), 'only lowercase strings supported'
    encrypted = ''
    for letter in msg:
        nth = string.ascii_lowercase.index(letter)
        new_index = (nth + shift) % len(string.ascii_lowercase)
        encrypted += string.ascii_lowercase[new_index]
    return encrypted
print(caesar_cipher('action', shift=4))  # egxmsr
```

To decode again, simply invert the sign of the shift used for encoding, i.e.:

```py
print(caesar_cipher('egxmsr', shift=-4))  # action
```

Support for uppercase letters could easily be added by using the letters provided by `string.ascii_uppercase`. Hope this helps!